# Spring Boot 2 Test: How Can I Have Just One EntityManager?

Tags: spring-boot, overriding, spring-boot-test

I'm migrating a project from Spring Boot 1.5 -> 2.2 and having a problem with bean overrides for an integration test for a wrapper class that configures `ModelMapper` for converting entity classes to dtos for delivery to the frontend.

In my `application-test.properties` file i allow bean overriding:

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`

I have a test configuration class that overrides the production `EntityManager` instance (or it did in Spring Boot 1.5...):

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.package")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "mockAuditorAware")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BackendTestConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "testEmf")
  @Primary
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.example");
    entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter( new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() );
    return entityManager;
  }
}testE
```

And a test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {WrapperTestConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.package")
class MyModelMapperTest {


  private MyModelMapper modelMapper;

  @Autowired
  LotteryModelMapperTest(MyModelMapper mm) {
    this.modelMapper = mm;
  }

  // test cases

}
```

If i run the test cases with the overridden bean present in the test configuration, the test fails

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
```

However, removing either of the configured `EntityManagerFactory` beans (test or production) results in

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

So i seem to either get two instances or zero instances. How do configure this so i override the bean in the production configuration with the one in the test configuration?

Comment: Why are you overriding it instead of just modifying the existing configuration?

Comment: @M.Deinum Because that's how i got it. And because removing the test bean instance results in no `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` being created in the test environment.

Comment: The bean isn't overriding (as it has a different name). But you should really remove it, also you are writing a `@SpringBootTest` which should, ideally, just load your application, together with a test based properties file to configure it for test. You shouldn't need that bean if your test was correct and correctly configured.